# asp.net website wcf data service authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows-phone-7, wcf-data-services

I am building a website using ASP.NET MVC 3 and have forms authetication setup correctly (user is able to register and login). I want to setup an OData WCF Data Services service so a Windows Phone 7 (Mango Beta 2 Refresh) client can authenticate and query the Odata service, with CRUD actions. This idea comes from the FullStack episodes [here](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/The-Full-Stack). They use OAuth login, but I wanted to use the user setup I already have, instead of an OAuth solution.

I do have this all working without auth currently (MVC app with Odata client on wp7), but am looking to make the Odata service secure. I guess I am looking for some articles or walkthroughs on how to get this working.

If forms authentication is not the correct choice, please let me know.

**UPDATE**

So lots of research done on this. There is an official how-to series on the blog for the WCF team [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/tags/authentication/). Since forms auth is already configured on the web app, adding a check inside the QueryInterceptor provides the auth. However it uses a 'standard authentication endpoint' for client apps to actually 'login' that seems to use the base Membership providers, which I don't use. Is there a way to override this?

Answer (score 2):

You could turn your custom forms authentication setup into a Claims based [Federated Authentication Provider](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federated_identity) (STS) using [Windows Identity Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa570351).  Then use that to authenticate your wp7 app with the STS provider and then send that claim (token) to your Odata service which will verify its an authentic claim.  There is an example of this in the [WIF training kit](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=14347)

Comment: This seemed very complicated, but I also found this example: http://www.leastprivilege.com/SecuringWCFDataServicesUsingWIF.aspx. I'm still on the fence whether I want to go so far as a federated authentication system for this.